# When should the "translatable" tag be added to a query?

Tags: 7, database

I noticed that a Drupal core function is using the following code.

```php
$categories = db_select('contact', 'c')
  ->addTag('translatable')
  ->fields('c', array('cid', 'category', 'recipients', 'selected'))
  ->orderBy('weight')
  ->orderBy('category')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAll();
```

When should a module add that tag to the query it is executing?

I take that adding that query tag has some effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On its own, that tag doesn't much (yet). This is the so called *Dynamic data translation* feature, an idea that was born from [Prepare Drupal core for dynamic data translation](http://drupal.org/node/593746).

Basically, you define in your `hook_schema()` (See [`contact_schema()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--contact--contact.install/function/contact_schema/7) for an example) which fields can be translated, and then add the "translatable" tag to all queries which fetch the data. Use `'translated' => TRUE'` for all those columns.

Then, what is *supposed* to happen is that a contributed module can maintain separate tables per language for your translatable columns, automatically join these tables, and replace the selected columns with those from translated table.

However, as far as I know, nobody has yet attempted to write such a module.